# SQL junction table naming: making it readable vs. following convention

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, naming, create-table

Consider the following "user" table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nick_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

Now I have a many-to-many reference table which connects 2 users in a
"following" relationship (which is not a two-way relationship btw).

I've read a lot about naming stuff in sql but most of the times it's
really inconsistent (some say PascalCase, some snake_case eg.).

My question is, which of the following naming is better?

readablity > convention:

```
CREATE TABLE user_following_user (
    follower_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    target_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ...
    PRIMARY KEY ...
)
```

convention > readability:

```
CREATE TABLE user_user_xref (
    user1_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user2_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ...
    PRIMARY KEY ...
)
```

Keep in mind that there may be other tables that also have 2 users in relation (say a blocking table), which is why I'm not sure what's the correct way to name (junction-) tables.

Maybe there's another way to follow conventions while maintaining readability. I appreciate every tip.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this common terminology issue: https://world.hey.com/jdmo/how-to-name-your-junction-tables-3735fdc9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for readability every time.  Be kind to the person maintaining your sql code; it may be you in 6 months from now.  Also, check where the "conventions" you are following come from.  What reason would anyone have for defining a convention that eliminates any explanation of what you are doing (like the second example)?
You may find this helpful: [the names we give things](http://www.thedatastudio.net/words_you_should_never_use.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure as I'm relatively new to everything-sql so your answer helps a lot!